# playing an mp3 file and loading a waveform image?

Tags: php, jquery, html, waveform

How can I play an mp3 and generate a wafeform image using HTML5 or Jquery?

Thanks Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Playing an audio file with HTML 5 is pretty straight forward:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Above Example from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

As for generating a waveform I'd check out [waveform.js](http://waveformjs.org/)

Comment: Hi DanO, Thanks for reply. Can you make sample waveform.js under http://localhost/music/horse.mp3.